# how to remove html tags in django template on browser while showing to user

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, ckeditor4.x, django-ckeditor

As shown in figure i used {{options|safe}} for rendering options in my django 3.0 polls application even though it is rendering like that and i don't know how to remove the

tags from rendered string, thanks for help in advance


regarding

tag error

Answer (score 1):

To remove tags, I would recommend using Mozilla's [bleach](https://pypi.org/project/bleach/) library.

In order to remove tags only in the front-end, not the data itself, you can easily create a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) and clean the tags inside it.

Another cool idea would be to have list of enabled HTML tags that can be used (like making text bold with `<b>...</b>`) and then render the input as a valid html:

```html
{{ options|remove_tags|safe }}
```

Example for a custom template filter:

```py
@register.filter
def remove_tags(value):
    return bleach.clean(value, tags=["b", "i"])
```

Comment: does it effects image uploading via django ck-editor

Comment: @mgbhargava no, it shouldn't, it is only how you render an output from a text field. However, it is only suggested to modify input from such editors before saving the model to make sure the user didn't add anything like javascript, frames or other ways of code injection using these rich text editors.